# Index is out of range even though debugging shows that it's in range?

Tags: vb.net

Below is a picture which might explain it better.  I have a list of parent nodes in a treeview and I go through each one to make sure that they have child nodes.  If they do then I go through each one of the child nodes in a for loop, but even when i = 0 it's telling me it's out of range, even though you can see that they exist.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They actually don't exist.
Notice right above that `childCount: 0`.

What you're seeing in the private array is pre-allocated space to hold any future children.

Comment: Then the for loop shouldn't even run?  It's

For i As Integer = 0 To rowNode.Nodes.Count - 1

And I checked and the count is 0, For i = 0 to -1 doesn't run the loop at all so why is it running the loop?

Comment: @Jake: Are you removing in the loop?